# Фильтрация результатов поиска google.com c помощью javaScript

Tags: javascript, массивы, href

Доброго времени суток!

Я пытаюсь отфильтровать все результаты поиска и сохранить их в переменной массива, потом показать все атрибуты href из массива.

С первой частью проблем нет, а вот со второй беда.

Вот, что у меня есть сейчас:
Я нашла div со всеми результатами и записала его в переменную, теперь пытаюсь вытащить все href.

```
    var searchResults = document.getElementsByClassName("g");   
    var array = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < searchResults.length; i++) {
            array.push(searchResults[i].href);
    }
    console.log(array);
```

Проблема в том, что такой способ не находит href в массиве результатов, хотя они внутри есть.

Comment: Вы уверены, что у блока `div` с классом `g` есть атрибут (свойство) `href`?

Comment: да, но он внутри другого `div`

Comment: Перепроверьте, добавив в существующий цикл `console.dir(searchResults[i])`

Comment: проверила, у блока `div` с классом `g`  нету атрибута `href`, но инспектируя `DOM` элементы `href` находится во внутренних `div`, которые внутри `div` с классом `g`

Comment: Ну так надо достучаться до элемента, у которого есть нужный атрибут, а не пытаться взять его у родительского элемента `array.push(searchResults[i].querySelector('a').href);`

Comment: Сработало! Как же я сама до этого не додумалась( Спасибо большое :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    var searchResults = document.getElementsByClassName("g");
    var links = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < searchResults.length; i++) {
            links.push(searchResults[i].querySelector('a').href);
    }
    console.log(links);
```